# Wordpress: Different template when pagination begins

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, pagination

I'm developing a theme for wordpress, It's all running very smooth.

I have a front page (on index.php) with a slider, carousel and "front page stuff", including the last 5 posts.

After those 5 posts I put a pagination link with  `<?php next_posts_link(); ?>`.

The thing I want to to is that when the user clicks the pagination link, the posts shown in the next page will have a different template, without the slider and carousel for example.

Maybe I can code an "if" statement using the url to "un-include" the slider and carousel if "url has ?paged=yadayada" or something like that but I find it not very elegant

Anyone ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to wrap the carousel and slider in `if ( is_home() ) { //do carousel and slider }`
This will only display them on your homepage.

Comment: I thought that was the best idea but it wouldn't work, I tried also is_front_page and nothing... I tried also @Ankit Pkhrel answer and then Ankit's answer mixed with yours hahahah nothing... maybe theres a variable that I can define or in functions.php that makes WP know whats the front page.

Comment: Try if `if (is_front_page() && !is_paged() )`

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a different page template as your need. You can check official wordpress doc to get started.

Wordpress Page Template Reference: http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates

Comment: You can use this tutorial (http://www.expand2web.com/blog/custom-page-template-wordpress/) for step by step tutorial on wordpress page template.